# glmer extracts coefficient only for main (predictor) factor, not contrast

Tags: r, lme4, summary, coefficients

here is the GLMER model

```
model <- glmer(ACC~Group*M_O*Lblock+ (1| Subject) + (1| hand),data = learndata_long3,family="binomial")
```

while the 'Lblock' factor has 9 levels, others have 2 levels.

The results generate like this:

```
     summary(model)$coefficients

                        Estimate Std. Error     z value      Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)          0.437931021 0.16334362  2.68104155  7.339340e-03
Group1              -0.032138148 0.14961572 -0.21480463  8.299196e-01
M_O1                 0.135726477 0.04115871  3.29763642  9.750230e-04
Lblock1              0.301264476 0.08343952  3.61057288  3.055214e-04
Lblock2              0.623913565 0.08247767  7.56463576  3.889529e-14
Lblock3              1.022046512 0.08235930 12.40960689  2.317880e-35
Lblock4              1.399407518 0.08337615 16.78426631  3.181367e-63
Lblock5              1.741198402 0.08541505 20.38514752  2.265326e-92
Lblock6              2.065315516 0.08843600 23.35378765 1.261292e-120
Lblock7              2.268393650 0.09075950 24.99345703 7.201546e-138
Lblock8              2.637079325 0.09707420 27.16560426 1.656429e-162
```

ALL I want is extract each factor, like"

Estimate : Group / M_O / Lblock

how can I do? just sum up and then mean the block? or ?

Very new to these fields, thanks for your help

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you need here. The estimates for each factor is listed in the Estimate column. I think what may be confusing you is that the Intercept corresponds to the reference level of each factor. So the intercept is the estimate for the other levels of your `M_O` factor and your `Group` factor as well as the ninth level of the `Lblock` factor. If this does not clarify things, please explain your issue more in depth.

Comment: what I want is only β*Group +  β*M_O + β*Lblock, but the result show each facter's contrast, like Lblock have  (Lblock1 + Lblock2…  )， what should I do with these ? and there are also   (Group2:M_O2                 1.951e-01  7.299e-02  1.235e+04   2.674 0.007515 ** 
Group2:Lblock2              1.193e-01  7.299e-02  1.235e+04   1.634 0.102249    
Group2:Lblock3              1.201e-01  7.311e-02  1.235e+04   1.643 0.100385    
Group2:Lblock4 ) , what is the exactly result should be reported.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying a bit. I think what you are expecting is something similar to the output of an ANOVA? But this will not be possible with your data, as you have two random effects specified.

As you are running a logistic regression, you should read up a bit on how to interpret them. (I'm just putting this here because you said you were new to this)

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/output/logistic-regression-analysis/

Now, if you want to test the contribution of one of your factors to to the model, you have to create nested models, and compare them with a likelihood-ratio test using the `anova()` function in R.

For example, let's say that you had the same model you had above, but without any interactions specified:

```
m1 <- glmer(ACC~Group+M_O+Lblock+ (1| Subject) + (1| hand),data = learndata_long3,family="binomial")
```

And then one without the Group predictor:

```
m2 <- glmer(ACC~M_O+Lblock+ (1| Subject) + (1| hand),data = learndata_long3,family="binomial")
```

Then we compare whether having the `Group` predictor significantly improved the model:

```
anova(m1,m2)
```

This will give your a p-value telling you if the addition of `Group` significantly improves model fit.

If this seems all like a lot, which it is if you're not familiar with model comparison, I'd recommend looking at this tutorial from Bodo Winter. It's directed at people who are new mixed-models, and want a conceptual foundation of what is going on. I don't know what field you are in, but I think the examples are pretty accessible to everyone.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5499

Please let me know if you need any other clarifications or have any questions during the tutorial.

Comment: Grateful reference papers, and I wonder after comparing these two model with anova(), it only showed the p value,but not one factor β, some one told me that I need to change my factor into nurmeric value.

Comment: No, so using the likelihood ratio test wont mabe any coefficient name appear, because you are evaluating the model as a whole. It's up to you to know how you've created your nested models so you can examine which predictor that is in one model and missing from the other is creating the difference. As for converting your factor into a numeric value, I don't know why that would be necessary here. If the person who told you to do it is a supervisor / professor of yours, I would probably do it, but make sure to ask them why so you understand the reasons motivating it.